# Looking for quote from a Native American from Wounded Knee era

Tags: quote-source

I stumbled across a quote by a Native American, in reference to the events following [Wounded Knee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wounded_Knee_Massacre).

I think I came across it on wikipedia in one of the entries referenced from the Wounded Knee page or the [Ghost dance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_Dance) page.

I'm not sure who was speaking but I remember that the quote mentioned that the "animals were gone", and that either the "circle was broken" or the "bow was broken" and that the person felt a devastating loneliness.

(The adjective devastating wasn't in there but the world "loneliness" definitely was.)

It's a powerful quote and I would be grateful to find it again.

Comment: Black Elk wrote "the nation's hoop is broken and scattered". He didn't mention animals or loneliness (explicitly) though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although some of the specifics are different, I think you are likely remembering the conclusion of *Black Elk Speaks,* which is presented as the as-told-to autobiography of Nicholas Black Elk, a spiritual leader of the Lakota nation.

> I did not know then how much was ended. When I look back now from this
> high hill of my old age, I can still see the butchered women and children lying
> heaped and scattered all along the crooked gulch as plain as when I saw them
> with eyes still young. And I can see that something else died there in the bloody
> mud, and was buried in the blizzard. A people’s dream died there. It was a
> beautiful dream.
>
> And I, to whom so great a vision was given in my youth,—you see me now a
> pitiful old man who has done nothing, for **the nation’s hoop is broken and
> scattered**. There is no center any longer, and the sacred tree is dead.

[http://public.gettysburg.edu/~franpe02/files/%5BJohn_G._Neihardt%5D_Black_Elk_Speaks__The_Complete_(z-lib.org).pdf](http://public.gettysburg.edu/%7Efranpe02/files/%5BJohn_G._Neihardt%5D_Black_Elk_Speaks__The_Complete_(z-lib.org).pdf)

In context, the quote was indeed spoken as a reaction to Wounded Knee, and (currently) appears on this Wikipedia page, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wounded_Knee_Massacre, making it more likely it was the one you saw. I thought at first you might have conflated several quotes, but I didn't see ones specifically referencing animals and "loneliness."

Comment: I think that I may have in fact conflated several quotes and created a false memory of a quote combining 'loneliness' and 'animals'.  I'm marking this as the accepted answer, although I'm also tempted to delete the question entirely since it can't be answered as posed. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In a 1992 book by Peter Nabokov, [*Native American Testimony: A Chronicle of Indian-white Relations from Prophecy to the Present, 1492-1992*](https://www.worldcat.org/title/26782619), there is a chapter that might be what you're thinking of. A [review](https://scholarscompass.vcu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1611&context=ess) of the book says:

> The last chapter of Part One has a summary title, "The Nation's Hoop is Broken and Scattered." In it, representative voices speak: a Kiowa writes "The Buffalo Go," a Cochise " I Am Alone," Crazy Horse as an Oglala Sioux "I Have Spoken," and an Omaha speaks of "This Awful Loneliness."

From the website of the publisher of the [paperback edition](https://www.penguinrandomhouse.com/books/331703/native-american-testimony-by-peter-nabokov/) of the book, here is a full list of the individual writings in this chapter. Perhaps you're remembering the chapter title's "Broken and Scattered" and the writings "Gone Forever" and "This Awful Loneliness."

> Chapter 9. The Nation’s Hoop is Broken and Scattered
>
> 1. The Buffalo Go (Old Lady Horse, Kiowa)
> 2. Take Care of Me (Wild Cat, Seminole)
> 3. I Am Alone (Cochise, Chiricahua Apache)
> 4. I Have Spoken (Crazy Horse, Oglala Sioux)
> 5. I Want to Look for My Children (Chief Joseph, Nez Percé)
> 6. No Dawn to the East (Anonymous, tribe unknown)
> 7. Gone Forever (Buffalo Bird Woman, Hidatsa)
> 8. This Awful Loneliness (Anonymous, Omaha)
> 9. A Wish (Flint Knife, Blackfoot)